# MCP3008 question about voltage

Tags: adc

I am using the MCP3008 as an ADC. What voltage is practical to be used? The datasheet for the MCP3008 specifies Vref = 5V and Vdd = 5V. Other comments I read in the forums is that the desired voltage is 3.3V as the 5V circuit is too much for the MCP3008 and could lead to failure.

I am using this with a Raspberry Pi.

Any comments about voltage?

Answer (score 3):

> Data sheet for MCP3008 specifies Vref = 5V and Vdd = 5v.

The [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21295d.pdf) specifies:

[image]

Take note that \$V_{REF,max} = V_{DD}\$.
If \$V_{DD} = 3.3V\$, you can't supply \$V_{REF}\$ any higher than 3.3V.

> Other comments I read in the forums is that the desired voltage is 3.3V as the 5V circuit is too much for the MCP3008 and could lead to failure.

These commenters are wrong. The manufacturer wouldn't specify \$V_{DD,max} = 5.5V\$ if it could lead to device failure.

That said, the operating voltage of the RPi I/O pins is 3.3V. Therefore you also want to connect \$V_{DD}\$ and \$V_{REF}\$ to 3.3V.

Answer (score 2):

The MCP3008 has two input voltages, VDD and VREF.

VDD is your supply voltage, and is used to power the internal circuitry of the chip. This means that your communication interface (SPI it looks like) will use VDD as its logic high level. As far as I know the Raspberry Pi uses 3.3V I/O, so you should use 3.3V for VDD so that you can directly connect the SPI interface between the RPi and the ADC.

VREF is you analog reference voltage. This is what you are measuring your signals against. This does not have to be equal to VDD, and has more to do with what signals you are measuring. Your ADC output will be with respect to this voltage level. For example, since this is a 10 bit ADC, if your VREF = 4V and your ADC output is 768, then your measured voltage is given by $$4V * \frac{768}{1024} = 3V$$

You should also note that you can only measure up to VREF, so if you want to measure 4V signals you should set VREF to 4V or higher. From what I can tell, you can set VREF and VDD to anything between 2.7 - 5.5V. The caveat here is that *VREF must be less than or equal to VDD* so if you use VDD = 3.3V then VREF must be 3.3V or less.

To summarize, the RPi I/O voltage dictates that you should set VDD to 3.3V, unless you use a level translator. This would limit your VREF input to 3.3V as well.

Comment: Except that VREF must not be higher that VDD, so if VDD is forced to be 3.3V to be able to communicate with Raspberry Pi, VREF must also be 3.3V or less.

Comment: @Justme Oops, forgot to include that. Will edit the answer now.